# Webform URL rerouting and session variable

Tags: asp.net, session, webforms, session-variables

We're spawning URLs in Excel projects tied to a specific project number.
Our main page Project.aspx is loading up the session variable ID to show the right values on the webpage.

So here's a concrete example of what we'd like to do:

> The user clicks a link in an excel spreadsheet  i.e.:
>   .../ProjectID=?12345
>
> The website code behind checks the ID and assigns it to the session
>   variable and then loads up our main page, Project.aspx

How can I achieve that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is save a query string value to the session state, then this might help:

```
Session["ProjectID"] = Request.QueryString["ProjectID"];
```

Note that you have a syntax error in your example, though...

```
.../ProjectID=?12345
```

should probably be:

```
.../?ProjectID=12345
```

Comment: @TommyLeblanc: I suppose so.  `Page_Load` should make sense if this is supposed to happen immediately when a page is called.  That's usually where WebForms handle input validation, and this qualifies as that.

Comment: Thanks David, the session variable is transfered now but I get an error when trying my Project.aspx page, in fact, the page doesn't read my jQuery anymore on my dynamic aspx page. The code-behind works since all the right values are in the right place but I have no jquery working whatsoever on the page

Comment: @TommyLeblanc: This sounds like a separate issue.  When you say "I have no jquery working" what exactly do you mean?  Is the jQuery library being loaded correctly in the page?  Everything jQuery-related would be happening client-side, so it has little to do with the server-side code.  Your best bet to debug jQuery issues is in browser debugging tools.

Comment: What I mean when I say there's no jQuery working is that even if I add a watch to the $ , i get nothing attached to it, the $ just doesn't exist. The same code works 100% when loading a project normally. It is somewhat related since it doesn't work only when I try to load up a project with a Querystring.

Comment: @TommyLeblanc: Could be as simple as a syntax error in your markup.  If there's no `$` object then the jQuery library isn't being loaded.  Check the `script` tag that references it.